# Drupal 6: Installation Profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-distributions

I've looked in Drupal.org on how to create an installation profile for Drupal 6 without luck. Have any of you guys worked on creating installation profiles. I need to know if there's a proper guide I could use to accomplish this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently wrote about using installation profiles in Drupal 6 [here](http://stonebergdesign.com/blog/installation-profiles-automating-basic-site-configuration-speed-development)

Comment: Wow, this is a really detailed article! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [Developing installation profiles](http://drupal.org/node/159730)? The starting-point for writing these install profiles.

Comment: Yes, documentation is mixed up between Drupal versions.